# Sometimes can't parse date from json using gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using gson 2.4 in my app in order to parse json object. The flow of the app is: get login json from server - save it to shared preference - get it when i need and parse back to a json object.

Example of a problematic json that I got from the server:

```
{".expires":"Mar 16, 2017 5:52:29 PM",".issued":"Dec 16, 2016 5:52:29 PM","access_token":"**"}
```

My code when i am getting the json back from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences settings = activity.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", 0);        
String json = settings.getString("LoginToken", null);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(Settings.DateFormat).create();
loginToken = gson.fromJson(json, LoginToken.class);
```

On the last line when i am using `gson.fromJson` I am getting an exception.

So  i tried to parse this json in my eclipse using this code:

```
String raw = "{\".expires\":\"Mar 16, 2017 5:52:29 PM\",\".issued\":\"Dec 16, 2016 5:52:29 PM\",\"access_token\":\"**"}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(Settings.DateFormat).create();
LoginToken loginToken = gson.fromJson(raw, LoginToken.class);
```

and it produced this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Mar 16, 2017 5:52:29 PM
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:814)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:779)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:728)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:700)
at **.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mar 16, 2017 5:52:29 PM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:105)
```

The date format i use is:

```
DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss";
```

Also tried to replace the `'T'` with a space but it didn't fix that.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Hang on, what do you mean by "sometimes"?

Comment: Most of the times gson is able to parse the json. sometimes it doesn't

Comment: probably in some cases the json is a little different. I am trying to use your suggestion right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match the date format in the data, so **in those cases your question refers to** your date format I needs to be:

```
"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
```

Comment: Now this json isn't working: ` {".expires":"31/03/2017 16:45:07",".issued":"31/12/2016 15:45:06","access_token":"**"}'

Comment: It's not going to. You need to use the correct format every time! There's no one format that's going to work for all.